# Php SOAP Parser

Tags: php, soap

Is there a ay that I can invoke php's SoapClient's internal parser?

I have a soap response as a string and I would like to parse it back to a php native datatype.

Is it possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOAP responses can be parsed with any of PHP's XML backends: DOMDocument, XMLReader, even SimpleXML.